# ERROR by deployApp("nameofApps")

Tags: r, shiny

I'm using the shiny package(v0.9.1). After executing the command deployApp("nameofApp") I got the following error. I couldn't find anyone, who had similar problem. May be someone can try explaining, how can I overcome this problem?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyapps)

runApp("nameofApp")    # works fine!
deployApp("nameofApp") # ERROR see below!
```

[Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 201442 error: Unhandled Exception: create: SQL error or missing database: no such table: entity]

Comment: Does your app use a data.frame named `entity`? If yes how do you load it in your app environment?

Comment: Hi, it uses no data.frame named *entity*. I'm loading only a helpers.R like mentioned in tutorials of Shiny. I have really no idea what can be the problem.

Comment: Sorry I cannot help... try to post in Shiny Google group maybe.